# Files uploaded by CKFinder have 411 as permission. How to set it to 777

Tags: drupal-7, ckfinder

CKFinder is working properly but files uploaded through CKFinder have 411 as permission. I want it to be 777. I would appreciate the help. Thanks!

Comment: I just tried to recreate this, but the files I uploaded were all set to 777. Interestingly, the parent directory is set to 755.

Can you tell us more about your setup? My environment is localhost, OS X on MAMP with the parent directory permissions (/sites/default/files/images) set to 755.

Answer (score 0):

I have EXACTLY the same problem.
Drupal 7, Dreamhost VPS server hosted, WYSIWYG installation with both ckeditor and finder in libraries sirectory tree.

ckfinder working fine, permissions set in ckfinder-bridge (https://drupal.org/project/WYSIWYG-CKFinder)

EXCEPT all files uploaded have 411 permissions so cant be accessed by the apache server after upload.

If I manually (via ssh) fix the permissions then the uploaded file can be used so this is purely an issue with permissions set during upload, and the permissions in ckfinder configuration are being ignored.

Comment: If this answer is only agreeing with the original question, then post it as a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: a) Stackoverflow is not giving me a 'comment' option, though it is allowing me to comment on your comment.
b) I was indicating more precisely where the issue is ie permissions are being messed up during the upload but once permissions set correctly on the server via alternate means then the rest of ckfinder functionality is ok.
c)The original answerer was using MAMP. I duplicated the original issue in a production server that ahs been working perfectly for several years and now this issue suddenly appears.

Comment: You comment by pressing the "add comment" button below posts, similar to how you commented on this.

Comment: I dont have an add comment option for the primary post.
Thought it was weird.
Anyway, irrelevant to the problem at hand.
Any ideas where this 411 permission is suddenly appearing from?